# Having trouble with nested If statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am having some difficulty using If statements in a Macro I am trying to write. Every month I receive a report in Excel that lists which employees at our company performed certain tasks. The Macro I'm writing is meant to copy and paste the data for each employee under their name in a master workbook.

The problem I'm running into is defining the range that I need to copy. As you'll see in the code, the employees are listed in column B. I start by searching for the employee in column B. If they don't exist, the macro copies and pastes (none) under their name in the master workbook. If it finds their name, it sets the row below their name as a first variable.

Here is where I run into a problem. The next step is to find the next employee listed, and set the row above as the second variable. Then I use the first and second variables to copy and paste that range of rows. I'm using an If statement to cycle through and find the next employee listed. However, my nested If statement is ending after my second Else if statement. Does anyone know a way I could write this better? I tried using Select Case statements but couldn't get the syntax right.

```
Sub EmployeeActivity()

Dim Employee1 As Integer, Employee2 As Integer, Employee3 As Integer, Employee4 As Integer
Dim EmployeeRange As Range, rngSelectFind As Range, rngPasteFind As Range

Windows("Activities Report.xlsm").Activate

Set rngSelectFind = Columns("B:B").Find(What:="Employee 1", After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
    Employee1 = rngSelectFind.Row + 1
ElseIf rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
    Set rngSelectFind = Columns("B:B").Find(What:="(none)", After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Consultant3 = rngSelectFind.Row
End If

Set rngSelectFind = Columns("B:B").Find(What:="Employee 2", After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
    Employee2 = rngSelectFind.Row - 1
ElseIf rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
    Set rngSelectFind = Columns("B:B").Find(What:="Employee 3", After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
            Employee2 = rngSelectFind.Row - 1
        End If
ElseIf rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
    Set rngSelectFind = Columns("B:B").Find(What:="(none)", After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
            Employee2 = rngSelectFind.Row - 1
        End If
End If

If Employee1 > 0 And Employee2 > 0 Then
    Set EmployeeRange = Range(Cells(Employee1, 2), Cells(Employee2, 7))
ElseIf Employee3 > 0 Then
    Set EmployeeRange = Range(Cells(Employee3, 2), Cells(Employee3, 7))
End If

EmployeeRange.Select
Selection.Copy


Windows("Monthly Activity Report.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("April '13").Activate
Set rngPasteFind = Columns("A:A").Find(What:="Employee Activities", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If Not rngPasteFind Is Nothing Then
Employee4 = rngPasteFind.Row + 1
End If

Range(Cells(Employee4, 1), Cells(Employee4, 6)).Select
Selection.Insert (xlShiftDown)


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help. Please let me know if I can provide additional context.

Comment: probably would be helpful if you can provide the file(s), anonymize the data if necessary (assuming it is work-related/possibly confidential/etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that I noticed.

1. Please do not use `.Activate` and `Selection`. Directly work with the object. You might want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179)
2. If you are using `.Find` then cater for instances when you won't find a match. You have done that at several places but then missed at some.
3. Do not declare `Employee1`, `Employee2` etc as `Integer`. In Excel 2007+, that can give you an error as Excel 2007+ supports 1048576 rows. use `Long` Instead.
4. I am not sure why are you copying the range `EmployeeRange` when you do not intend to paste it anywhere? I see that you are declaring a `Paste` Range though...

See this code. Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub EmployeeActivity()
    Dim Employee1 As Long, Employee2 As Long, Employee3 As Long, Employee4 As Long
    Dim EmployeeRange As Range, rngSelectFind As Range, rngPasteFind As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Workbook

    '~~> Change path as applicable
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Activities Report.xlsm")
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Change path as applicable
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Monthly Activity Report.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("April '13")

    With ws
        Set rngSelectFind = .Columns("B:B").Find(What:="Employee 1", _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
            Employee1 = rngSelectFind.Row + 1
        Else
            Set rngSelectFind = .Columns("B:B").Find(What:="(none)", _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext)

            If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
                Consultant3 = rngSelectFind.Row
            End If
        End If

        Set rngSelectFind = Nothing

        Set rngSelectFind = .Columns("B:B").Find(What:="Employee 2", _
                             LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
            Employee2 = rngSelectFind.Row - 1
        Else
            Set rngSelectFind = .Columns("B:B").Find(What:="Employee 3", _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext)

            If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
                Employee2 = rngSelectFind.Row - 1
            Else
                Set rngSelectFind = .Columns("B:B").Find(What:="(none)", _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                If Not rngSelectFind Is Nothing Then
                    Employee2 = rngSelectFind.Row - 1
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If Employee1 > 0 And Employee2 > 0 Then
            Set EmployeeRange = .Range(.Cells(Employee1, 2), _
                                       .Cells(Employee2, 7))
        ElseIf Employee3 > 0 Then
            Set EmployeeRange = .Range(.Cells(Employee3, 2), _
                                       .Cells(Employee3, 7))
        End If
    End With

    '~~> I am not sure why are you copying this range???
    If Not EmployeeRange Is Nothing Then EmployeeRange.Copy

    With ws1
        Set rngPasteFind = .Columns("A:A").Find(What:="Employee Activities", _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rngPasteFind Is Nothing Then
            Employee4 = rngPasteFind.Row + 1
            .Range(.Cells(Employee4, 1), .Cells(Employee4, 6)).Insert (xlShiftDown)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**TIP**: You can create a common `.Find` function which can accept parameters. That ways you can drastically reduce your above code ;)

**EDIT**

See this example (*UNTESTED*) which demonstrates the above tip. This way you do not need to use `.Find` again and again in the code.

```
Sub EmployeeActivity()
    Dim Employee1 As Long, Employee2 As Long
    Dim Employee3 As Long, Employee4 As Long
    Dim EmployeeRange As Range, rngSelectFind As Range, rngPasteFind As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Workbook

    '~~> Change path as applicable
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Activities Report.xlsm")
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Change path as applicable
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Monthly Activity Report.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("April '13")

    With ws
        Employee1 = GetRow(ws, 2, "Employee 1")

        If Employee1 <> 0 Then
            Employee1 = Employee1 + 1
        Else
            Consultant3 = GetRow(ws, 2, "(none)")
        End If

        '
        'And So on
        '
End Sub

Function GetRow(wks As Worksheet, ColNo As Long, SearchString As String) As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = wks.Columns(ColNo).Find(What:=SearchString, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        GetRow = 0
    Else
        GetRow = rng.Row
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Excellent thank you! It took me a little while to clean the Macro with your suggestions, but everything ran perfectly. I really appreciate the help.